# Can't get the value of an form input

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, pug

I am using a pug template to expose an array of objects, formatted as a table.  Here is the pug template:

```
each trans,index in property.transactions

 .tr                                                                        
       .td
             input.transInput(type="text", name=`salesPrice${index}`, id=`salesPrice${index}`, value=(trans.salesPrice).toLocaleString('en', { style: 'currency',  currency: 'USD', minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0}))
```

I am trying to build a RestAPI to make edits, but when I try to get the value of the "salePrice", I am getting a "null" value.

This is the javaScript code:

```
if (updateTransaction)
updateTransaction.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

e.preventDefault();
const price = document.getElementById('salesprice0');
const price2 = document.getElementById('salesPrice1');

console.log(price, price2);
```

});`

When I check the developer tools, the value is correct.  See below:

```
<input class="transInput" type="text" name="salesPrice0" id="salesPrice0" value="$1,000,000" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your capitalization: `salesprice0` does not equal `salesPrice0`. Note the capital P.

You need to be more careful and observant to these tiny details. Computers see them as differences.